# PHPWord - cannot open saved file because don't have 'access priveleges'

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

Im using PHPWord to make a document from a template, its all worked great so far and the documentation is fairly decent: http://phpword.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

But I cannot open the file that I have created, using:

```
$templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
```

It says word cannot open as user does not have access privileges. I don't see anything in the documentation about this and searching SO finds several other similar questions all unanswered.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Does it says about contact the administrator?

Comment: No just: Word cannot open the document: user does not have access privileges. The help box says its been saved with permissions but no idea how not to save with permissions. Maybe I shall just try and find a different php to docx library instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I worked it out. Thanks to @John Smith for helping to steer me in the right direction. I found the answer here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/532

Basically i changed the function saveAs from:

```
rename($tempFilename, $strFilename);
```

to:

```
copy($tempFilename, $strFilename);
unlink($tempFileName);
```

and it now works a dream. Thanks again @John Smith for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually I think :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

```
// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);
```

Comment: Ok great that looks promising, what do I do with it though. I tried this: $templateProcessor->saveAs(chmod($source, 0644)); am I way adrift? Also tried adding chmod($source, 0644); after my original saveas() line

Comment: Nope. Just do `$templateProcessor->saveAs($filename); chmod($filename, 0644); `

Comment: Yeah was just reading through that and i worked it out. Cheers for the help.

Comment: I posted the actual answer that solved it or me below. Thanks again for the help.